# Can one have a ragged array as an intermediate step inside Compile?

Tags: compile

I am aware that one should avoid (or be very careful) with ragged arrays as input or output of compiled functions. I, however, would like to be able to have a ragged array as an *intermediate* result within `Compile`. For instance, I would like to do something like this

```
example = Compile[{{range, _Integer}},
   Flatten[
    Table[
     Table[j, {j, i, range}]
     , {i, 1, range}]
    ]
   , CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Evaluating

```
example[3]
```

results in

```
CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.
{1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3}
```

Is there a way to have a ragged array as an intermediate result within `Compile`? Obviously, the thing I actually want to do is much more complicated than this example.

Comment: The answer is "no". Fullstop. You can of course create an oversized array, write into it, and only return the relevant parts at the end.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, that's too bad, but good to know anyway. I'll then have to work around this as you suggested.

Comment: Kind of "yes", but not recommended. See [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271053/17) under another question for details.