# How to convert the ListVector into PackedArray in FunctionCompile

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, conversion, packed-arrays

**Cross post [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2577978?p_p_auth=NM9rjpZF)**

---

I have a compile function `cf` to calculate the mean for *a ragged list*:

```
groups = N[{{40, 23, 213, 79, 18, 152, 105, 191, 119, 243}, {86, 3, 152, 89, 
     52, 36, 132, 196, 159, 108, 200}, {253, 223, 167, 197, 147, 112, 
     225, 98, 159, 163, 245, 240, 267}, {89, 164, 156, 124, 15, 253, 
     41, 171, 209, 132}}];

cf = FunctionCompile[
  Function[Typed[groups, "ListVector"::["ListVector"::["Real64"]]], 
   Mean[Cast[Catenate[groups], "PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]]]]

cf[groups]
```

> `141.955`

It works indeed. But I have to use **the highly in-efficient** `"ListVector"::["ListVector"::[*]]` for the following `Catenate`. Then I have to use a **very time-consuming** `Cast` for the following `Mean` in the code. This leads to a disastrous efficiency:

```
lis = DeleteCases[Table[ResourceFunction["RandomSplit"][RandomReal[255, 1000], 10],100000], {}, {2}];

Timing[Mean@*Catenate /@ lis;]
Timing[cf /@ lis;]
```

> {2.70313, Null}
>
> {9.92188, Null}

This is obviously a bit unbearably slow. I note [the documentation of "ListVector"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/compiledtype/ListVector.html):
[image]
So I think there must be a more efficient way to replace `Cast`, but the documentation is not perfect at the moment and I can't find any relevant examples to do this

Comment: I'd suggest not to concatenate the lists in order to compute the mean, but to sum their totals (`Total[lis,2]` should do) and then divide by `Total[Length/@list]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks. :) I'm obviously not interested in knowing the average about the ragged List in this post, but how to use and convert the "ListVector"

Answer (score 16):

### Edit

Regarding the direct question in OP, i.e. how to flatten a "ragged" array inside `FunctionCompile`, I have to say there might be ready-to-use method but I'm not aware of any, so I'd propose to just roll your own, something like this:

```
flatten = FunctionCompile@
 Function[
   Typed[groups, "ListVector"::["PackedArray"["Real64", 1]]]
   , Module[{lensVec, totalLen, buffer, i}
         , lensVec = Length /@ groups // Developer`ToPackedArray
         ; totalLen = Total[lensVec]
         ; buffer = ConstantArray[Typed[0, TypeOf[groups[[1]][[1]]]], totalLen]
         ; i = 1;
         ; Do[Do[
                  buffer[[i]] = groups[[gidx]][[j]]; i++;
               , {j, lensVec[[gidx]]}]
            , {gidx, Length@groups}]
         ; buffer
     ]
  ]

TakeList[RandomReal[1, 20], {8, 10, 2}] // Echo[#, "in", Grid] & // flatten
(*
>> in  0.836502 0.14191   0.799241 0.851397 0.0942267 0.124684 0.589021 0.444985    
       0.239656 0.0272972 0.88519  0.860003 0.592972  0.663511 0.133296 0.927317 0.240553 0.469914
       0.217146 0.233076                      

Out[]= {0.836502, 0.14191, 0.799241, 0.851397, 0.0942267, 0.124684, \
0.589021, 0.444985, 0.239656, 0.0272972, 0.88519, 0.860003, 0.592972, \
0.663511, 0.133296, 0.927317, 0.240553, 0.469914, 0.217146, 0.233076}
*)
```

---

From my personal experience, `"ListVector"`, as a general purpose expression container, is inefficient for such kind of computing -- much like in normal Wolfram language code where `Sin[ a (* <- non-packed array *) ]` is relatively inefficient than `Sin[ a (* <- packed array *) ]`. As I understand, in OP's case `"ListVector"` is needed to contain a "ragged array", but the usage should be limited to absolute needed. For example, here we can use `"ListVector"::["PackedArray"["Real64", 1]]` instead to achieve a better performance:

```
$Version
(* 13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022) *)

cf2 = FunctionCompile@Function[
      Typed[groups, "ListVector"::["PackedArray"["Real64", 1]]]
      , Module[{len = Length@groups, total, lenFull, mean}
            , lenFull = Length /@ groups // Developer`ToPackedArray // Total
            ; total = Total /@ groups // Developer`ToPackedArray // Total
            ; mean = Divide[total, lenFull]
       ]
   ]
```

It's much faster than `cf` described in OP:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Mean@*Catenate /@ lis;]
(* {5.26528,Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[cf /@ lis;]
(* {22.5891,Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[cf2 /@ lis;]
(* {0.508823,Null} *)
```

The code can be further optimized. In `cf2` I used `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` to cast a `"ListVector"[*]` (e.g. from `Length /@ groups`) to `"PackedArray"[*, 1]`, because `Total` is not defined on `"ListVector"[*]` type. But that casting introduces data copy, a familiar reason to slow down the compiled code just like similar case when using the good old `Compile`. On the other hand, by guessing, I found `Sum` is able to iterate along the `"ListVector"` directly, so here is a slightly faster one:

```
cf3 = FunctionCompile@Function[
      Typed[groups, "ListVector"::["PackedArray"["Real64", 1]]]
      , Module[{len = Length@groups, lenFull, total, mean}
            , lenFull = Sum[Length[groups[[i]]], {i, len}]
            ; total = Sum[Total[groups[[i]]], {i, len}]
            ; mean = Divide[total, lenFull]
       ]
   ]

AbsoluteTiming[cf3/@lis;]
(* {0.285133,Null} *)
```